# How to set height and width after rotate of overlay image on surface view

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set dynamic image on an ImageView but overlay of surface view and perform some basic image edit operation like scaling, rotation and transformation. Now while I rotate the ImageView with screen rotation in landscape mode it takes portrait mode height and width. I locked my activity in portrait mode.

[image: landscape mode-- overlay image on surface view][image: portrait mode image on surface view]

```
final int ROTATION_O    = 0;
final int ROTATION_90   = 90;
final int ROTATION_180  = 180;
final int ROTATION_270  = 270;

private int rotation = 0;
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
    if( (orientation < 35 || orientation > 325) && rotation!= ROTATION_O){ // PORTRAIT
        rotation = ROTATION_O;
        imgView.setRotation(rotation);
    }
    else if( orientation > 145 && orientation < 215 && rotation!=ROTATION_180){ // REVERSE PORTRAIT
        rotation = ROTATION_180;
        imgView.setRotation(rotation);
    }
    else if(orientation > 55 && orientation < 125 && rotation!=ROTATION_270){ // REVERSE LANDSCAPE
        rotation = ROTATION_270;
        imgView.setRotation(rotation);
    }
    else if(orientation > 235 && orientation < 305 && rotation!=ROTATION_90){ //LANDSCAPE
        rotation = ROTATION_90;
        imgView.setRotation(rotation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This library can help you

[uCrop](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop)

I think maybe if you get height and width when screen operation change can fix your problem

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: there is nothing in this library?.. @Radesh

Comment: No, its not useful  for me. I just want Rotate, zoom-in/zoom-out and drag image overlay on surface view. Crop not useful  for me now but best library

Comment: you mean image screen or device screen or none !?

Comment: i want only rotate imageview with screen orientation.. and while I rotate imageview on landscape mode it take width for landscape mode... size of  portrait mode width. so problem occur when i zoom  image that time it remain space beside the imageview and then zoom/drag in specific area.